# When using <audio> in html can I add a download link withing the player?

Tags: html, audio, download, embed

I want to add a html5 audio player to a page on my website, but I want people to be able to download the track as well.
Obviously i could just ad a link near by for that, but i would like to have a button within the player itself. Is this possible? I've haven't seen any examples with this feature.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<audio controls="controls" controls="download"> <br>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /><br>
</audio>
<a href="http://music.com/music.mp3">Download audio </a>
```